# Dimensional Analysis Conversion

Tags: dimensional-analysis, chemistry

I am new to learning about dimensional analysis and I am confused with a question. I am supposed to convert 45 km/day to inches/week. I would like to have all work shown. The work I have so far is shown below, I am not sure how to convert days to week and if I am supposed to multiply or divide by 7.

45 km/day to inches/week
45km * 1000m/1km * 1000mm/1m * 1cm/10mm * 1 in/2.54 cm

So so far I have that 45km is 1771653.543 inches/day. I am not sure how to convert this to weeks now. Any help is appreciated thank you!!

Comment: Tag (chemistry)?? A joke?

Answer (score 1):

You want "weeks" in the denominator, so you need to find some way days relate to weeks. We know that there are 7 days in 1 week, so we use that relation here. The reason we want weeks in the denominator and thus days in the numerator is because we want "days" to cancel algebraically. So: $${1771653.543 \text{ inches}\over 1 \text{ day}} \cdot \left({7 \text{ days}\over 1 \text{ week}}\right) = \;\;\;\;\cdots?$$